# Navigationbar and statusbar color for v21 in Android app (no theme libraries)

Tags: android, colors, themes, statusbar, navigationbar

I'm working on some app that I did not create and I wanted to set navbar and notificationbar colors for API 21 and up. The theme of the app is pure XML without the new app theme stuff libraries. Can I even set those colors having such a weird theme setup and using only xml? Can someone explain noob friendly what to add where?

I tried various stuff with

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

But I always seem to confuse things.

---

I only have themes.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.phttpp.TitleBar" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/windowTitleBackgroundStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/windowTitleStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
  </style>
  <style name="Theme.dialog.TitleBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/windowTitleStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and

styles.xml in values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="windowTitleBackgroundStyle">
    <item name="android:background">#00BCD4</item>
  </style>
  <style name="windowTitleStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:padding">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00BCD4</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that works for API21 and up.
I did not change anything in themes and styles, but I added colors.xml to /values-v21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#00BCD4</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#008394</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#33c9dc</color>
    <color name="colorGray">#e0e0e0</color>
</resources>
```

And added this to my main activity to onCreate in my Java code

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
    }
```